# How to enable/see Org Sync Log tab in Salesforce

Tags: integration, tab, salesforce2salesforce

I am trying to figure out how I can see Org Sync Log tab in Salesforce - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_partnernetworksynclog.htm

I have a connection tab which I could see from My Setting -> Customize tab but I could not find where the Org Sync Log tab is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have permissions to see Org sync tabs . Also see the below link to userguide ,

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/organization_sync.pdf